# How can I get the output of the query below into one result set in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql

I only have only "read" permissions to the database.  I am trying to pull data out of several tables with the same fields.  I am pulling the table names from the information_schema and putting them into a variable.  How can I get all the data from each SELECT into one result set?

```
DECLARE @acct_code AS VARCHAR(40)
       ,@chk_tbl AS VARCHAR(40)

DECLARE CKTable_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table_name
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
     WHERE table_name LIKE 'CK%'
       AND table_name > 'CK000000'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

OPEN CKTable_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CKTable_Cursor
  INTO @chk_tbl

SET @acct_code = SUBSTRING(@chk_tbl,3,LEN(@chk_tbl))

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

   EXEC    
         ('SELECT ck.inserteddatetime AS [Inserted Datetime]
                          ,actcode AS [Account Code]
                          ,actname AS [Account Name]
                          ,chk_num AS [Check Number]
                          ,payee AS [Payee]
                          ,supplier AS [Supplier]
                          ,balance AS [Balance]
                     FROM dbo.' +  @chk_tbl + ' AS ck WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.ChtActs AS coa WITH (NOLOCK)
                           ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),actcode) = ' + @acct_code)

FETCH NEXT FROM CKTable_Cursor
    INTO @chk_tbl

SET @acct_code = SUBSTRING(@chk_tbl,3,LEN(@chk_tbl))

END

CLOSE CKTable_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE CKTable_Cursor;
```

Comment: Tips: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. `@acct_code` should be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will use them going forward.

Comment: the reason you use quotename is your data field could contain an apostrophe which would need to be replace with ''